# Create a user with all privileges in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I was googling about how to create a user and grant all privileges to him.

I found these two methods :

The first method :

```
create user userName identified by password;
grant connect to userName;
grant all privileges to userName;
```

The second method :

```
grant connect , resource to userName identified by password;
```

So what's the difference between those two methods ?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

There are 2 differences:

**2 methods creating a user and granting some privileges to him**

```
create user userName identified by password;
grant connect to userName;
```

and

```
grant connect to userName identified by password;
```

do exactly the same. It creates a user and grants him the connect role.

**different outcome**

resource is a role in oracle, which gives you the right to create objects (tables, procedures, some more but no views!). ALL PRIVILEGES grants a lot more of system privileges.

To grant a user **all privileges** run you first snippet or

```
grant all privileges to userName identified by password;
```

Comment: When I execute the command  grant all privileges to testuser identified by testuser;  I get the error as "ORA-65052: statement involves operations with different container scope"   Any clue on this?  I am using Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: I am getting "ORA-65049: Creation of local user or role is not allowed in this container."

Answer (score 4):

My issue was, i am unable to create a view with my "scott" user in oracle 11g edition. So here is my solution for this

**Error in my case**

SQL>`create view v1 as select * from books where id=10;`

insufficient privileges.

Solution

1)open your cmd and change your directory to where you install your oracle database.
  in my case i was downloaded in E drive so my location is 
   E:\app\B_Amar\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN>
after reaching in the position you have to type sqlplus sys as sysdba

E:\app\B_Amar\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN>sqlplus sys as sysdba

2) Enter password: here you have to type that password that you give at the time of installation of oracle software.

3) Here in this step if you want create a new user then you can create otherwise give all the privileges to existing user.

**for creating new user**

SQL> `create user abc identified by xyz;`

here abc is user and xyz is password.

**giving all the privileges to abc user**

SQL> `grant all privileges to abc;`

```
 grant succeeded.
```

if you are seen this message then all the privileges are giving to the abc user.

4) Now exit from cmd, go to your SQL PLUS  and connect to the user i.e enter your username & password.Now you can happily create view.

**In My case**

in cmd `E:\app\B_Amar\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN>sqlplus sys as sysdba`

SQL> `grant all privileges to SCOTT;`

```
grant succeeded.
```

Now I can create views.