# Import data from Oracle(Windows) to HDFS (CDH3) machine using sqoop

Tags: hadoop, oracle11g, sqoop, bigdata

Hi I am taking a training in `HADOOP`. I have a task in which I have to import a tables data from oracle(windows, 11g xe) to `hdfs` using `sqoop`. I am reading the following article. My question is that how do I exactly import data from windows to hdfs. Noramally I use `Winscp` to transfer files from Windows to hdfs machine. I have imported data from `MySql` which was installed in hdfs(cdh3) machine. But I don't know to import data from Oracle in windows to hdfs. Please help.

[Link that I am following](http://www.rittmanmead.com/2014/03/using-sqoop-for-loading-oracle-data-into-hadoop-on-the-bigdatalite-vm/)

Comment: are you using custom built hadoop environment or using any readymade flavours like CDH or HDP or any other?

Answer (score 4):

Following is the step wise process:

**1**.Connect oracle sql command line log in with your credentials:

e.g username : system password: system

(make sure that this user has all administrative privileges or connect as sysdba in oracle make a new user with all privilegdes)
[Create a user with all privileges in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22386976/create-a-user-with-all-privileges-in-oracle)

Create tables under that user and insert some values and **commit**

**2**.Now we need a connector for transferring our data from Oracle to HDFS.
So, we need to download the oracle -sqoop connector jar file and place it in the following path of CDH3.(use sudo in your commands while copying in the following path as it requires admin acess in linux)

```
/usr/lib/sqoop/bin
```

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html   --Download link--ojdbc6.jar

Use winscp to transfer the downloaded jar from windows to CDH3.then move it to the above mentioned path in CDH3.

**3**.Command:

```
sudo bin/sqoop import –connect jdbc:oracle:thin:system/system@192.168.XX.XX:1521:xe–username system -P –table system.emp –columns “ID” –target-dir /sqoopoutput1 -m 1
```

sqoopoutput is the ouput file in HDFS where you will get your data ,U can change dis as per your

-m 1 : this tells the number no of mappers for this sqoop job here it is 1.

192.168.XX.XX:1521--ip address of your windows machine

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to import data from oracle to local machine. Then copy it to HDFS machine. Then import it in HDFS.

**Sqoop** is here to import your RDBMS tables in HDFS directory.

Use command:

`sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.xx.xx.xx:1521:ORCL' --username testuser --password testpassword --table testtable --target-dir /tmp/testdata`

Go to the machine on which sqoop is running.  Go to the terminal (*I believe its linux*). Just fire above mentioned command and check `--target-dir` (*I mentioned `/tmp/testdata` in the example command*) in hdfs. You will find files corresponding to your oracle table there.

Check sqoop [docs](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.5/SqoopUserGuide.html#_purpose) for more details.

Comment: So I need to take a backup and copy this back up file in CDH3 machine using Winscp and then using sqoop pull it in HDFS.? Am I right.?

Comment: @user2998990 no no. you don't need to copy anything. sqoop will do everything. You just provide valid credentials for oracle.