# Issues with username and password when connecting to oracle database 12c through ojdbc

Tags: java, sql, oracle12c

I have SQL developer installed and a properly configured DB, I create a user from sys like so:

```
CREATE USER random IDENTIFIED BY 12345;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO random;
```

I attempt to connect to the oracle SQL database with the ojdbc8.jar found in oracles website like this:

```
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:random/12345@localhost:1521:home";
try{
        Connection dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
}catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

However I receive this error:

```
Exception: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

The last time I asked this question it was just populated by answers that have no actual answer to the problem at hand, I don't need to change the driver to a different one, I don't need to instantiate some sort of factory nonsense that just adds complexity, all I want to know is how I'm meant to connect to an account that is part of my DB so I can perform basic SQL functions.

Edit:
It just occurred to me that it is a pdb, is there a modification needed to the connection url that anyone can point out?

Comment: Before you spend a lot of time chasing your tail; does it work when you use sql plus with that usename and password?

Comment: flush privileges?

Comment: Also, I seem to remember Oracle being finicky about how grants are given in some cases (with or with out identified by etc.).  You might try looking at some of these posts: https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-create-a-user-and-grant-permissions-in-oracle/, http://www.petefinnigan.com/ramblings/how_to_grant_all_privs.htm, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22386976/create-a-user-with-all-privileges-in-oracle

Comment: I do not see any users I have created inside sqlplus, but I have them in sql developer and I'll take a look at your link.

Comment: select  * from all_users might give you some additional useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Connection dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:home", "random", "12345");
```

Answer (score 0):

PDB connections need a slight tweak.

Please use `localhost:port/sid` instead of `localhost:port:sid`:

```java
if (isPluggableDB) {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + hostName + ":" + hostPort + "/" + sid, userName, password);
} else {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + hostName + ":" + hostPort + ":" + sid, userName, password);
}
```